# Is it possible to write constraint on table that primary key not equal to column4

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an tbl_User table  as follows
Table1

```
Id       Name        ReportingId
==
1        Stala       Null
2        Coma        1
3        Rita        1
4        Rosy        2
```

I have to restrict that :

```
Id       Name        ReportingId
==
1        Stala       1
2        Coma        2
3        Rita        3
4        Rosy        4
```

I have to restrict that **CASE 2** :

```
Id       Name        ReportingId
==
1        Stala       1
2        Coma        5
3        Rita        3
4        Rosy        8
```

Is this possible by giving constraint on table?

or

If any other simple ways that should not hamper performance of the table?

Answer (score 8):

Add a check constraint to prevent these values after creating the table:

```
alter table Table1 add CONSTRAINT ck_reportingId check(ReportingId <> Id)
```

Comment: Is it possible to check constraint on id exist on table

Comment: ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table1_ReportingID FOREIGN KEY (ReportingId) REFERENCES Table1(Id). If you want to delete all child references when you delete the parent record, add "ON DELETE CASCADE" to the end of this query.